# netbeans (java) shows empty window in tiling window manager (awesome wm)

Tags: java, window-manager, netbeans, awesome-wm

I use the "awesome" (tiling) window manager (with default config) and want to run netbeans (java app).

But the window is completely grey. The installer window was it too, so i installed under KDE.

I guess it has to do how java talks to the deskop or WM but found it hard to find the right keywords to search for this issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The JVM contains a hard-coded list of non [re-parenting window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-parenting_window_manager) such as Awesome.  You can fix this by using the `wmname` utility provided by suckless.org in the package `suckless-tools` to set the window manager name property of the root window:

```
sudo apt-get install suckless-tools
```

then

```
wmname LG3D
```

or

```
wmname compiz
```

Then restart or launch your Java application.

I've confirmed this to be working on JDK 1.7u3 with Netbeans 7.1 on Ubuntu 11.10/Awesome.

For additional details, check out Awesome's wiki on the [issue](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java).

Comment: had the same issue with xmonad, this fixed it

Comment: On that wikipedia article, it says xmonad is not reparenting: "Virtually all modern window managers are re-parenting [...] Exceptions to that rule are dwm, PLWM, ratpoison and xmonad, due to a lack of any typical window decorations used by these window managers"

Answer (score 3):

You can define an environment variable that says your WM is non-reparenting:

```
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
```

[source](https://github.com/UprootLabs/swing-htabs/issues/22)